# cannot differentiate views in layout when using addView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using addView to add views to my layout and setting onClick method on each of them to remove it from layout.

Thing is when I add for example two items only the **last added views** click working but the other reacts to nothing.

```
RelativeLayout inf = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_table_edit, null);
ImageView delete = inf.findViewById(R.id.delete);
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    addMap.removeView(inf);
                }
            });
addMap.addView(inf);
```

How can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: addMap is also RelativeLayout

Comment: Is your onClick method being called?

Comment: yes it is called and it is deleting the last view that added, after this delete is not working for view that left on layout.

Comment: If you are adding multiple views to the `addMap` than please put that code here.

Comment: I'm adding them by click to recyclerview items, it is as same as above code. All of them is the same, there are no different thing.

Comment: Is your `addMap`  recycleview item?

Comment: no, absolutely no. RecyclerView doesn't relate to this issue, I'm just using onItemClick function of it to recall code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
addMap.removeView(inf);
```

To

```
addMap.removeView((View) view.getParent());
```